# JavaScript code explanation for this sample?

Tags: javascript

**Hello everyone!** I have completed a couple of brief courses in JavaScript, and I have now moved on to *Heads Up: JavaScript*, which has been a lot of fun and is helping to cement my learning. I did run into something I didn't understand, though. In the following piece of code, I understand what the program generally does when it executes, but in attempting to trace each step of execution, I realized that I am confounded by the "What/Why/How" of a particular segment. Here's the code for the sample program I'm looking at:

---

```
function makePhrases() {

            var words1 = ["24/7", "multi-tier", "30,000 foot", "B-to-B", "win-win"];

            var words2 = ["empowered", "value-added", "oriented", "focused", "aligned"];

            var words3 = ["process", "solution", "tipping-point", "strategy", "vision"];



            var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);

            var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);

            var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);



            var phrase = words1[rand1] + " " + words2[rand2] + " " + words3[rand3];

            alert(phrase);

        }

        makePhrases();
```

---

This is the segment that has been confusing for me:

```
            var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);

            var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);

            var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);
```

I get that it's the part of the code that randomizes which item from each array is chosen to form the new "random phrase", but I don't understand how it's doing so. I also hadn't known previously that Math.random or Math.floor could be applied to strings (must be because they're in an array, which is essentially a number?), or the how/why of using Math.random or Math.floor with strings.

Additionally, why do we need to use .length with this incarnation? What does it do? I appreciate your wisdom here, and taking the time to help someone who's new to coding, and still has so much to learn!

Comment: @ David W, Halcyon, Matt Burland & Tom Sarduy --- THANK YOU!!! That makes a lot more sense now, these explanations really help. I guess my last question then is, when we're creating the index in words1, this is what tells the script how many items it has to choose from within the array, essentially setting an upper limit for what number it can choose, which is then correlated with a particular slot in the array (once we round it down to a whole number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the code:

```
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
```

`Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `0.999999..`.

`words1` is the list of words to choose from.

`words1.length` is the size of the list, the number of items, `5` in this case.

`Math.random() * words1.length` returns a number between `0` and `4.99999..`.

Finally use `Math.floor()` to get a whole number between `0` and `4`.

This number is then used as an index in `words1`, so `words1[rand1]`.

---

So the `Math` operations are never used on a string, fetching the string in only the last step.

Answer (score 2):

All that's happening is Math.random() is being used as a multiplier against the number of elements in the respective arrays (the '.length' property) to create an index value. It isn't being applied to a string; just as part of an expression to determine an index into a string array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pick a random element from an array. So you need an index, in other words a random number from `0` to `4` (because your length is `5`). `Math.random` will give you a random number between `0` and `1` (exclusive of 1). So to turn that into a random number between 0 and 4 you need to multiple by the length of `5`.

Then, since we need an integer, not a floating point number, we use `Math.floor` to truncate it to a integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.random()  //Return a random number between 0-1
words1.length()  //Return the length of the array
Math.floor()     //Return the closest integer less than or equal to a given number.
```

**Now the expressions:**

```
(Math.random() * words1.length)
```

Will return a random number between 0 and the length of the array. Could be a float, like 3,4 for example:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length)
```

Will return an **integer** number between 0 and the length of the string, so you can use it now as the string (behaving like an array) indexer.

**Note:** Note that the random number is between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), that's why is secure to use `Math.floor()`, to avoid an exception, and that's why is not used `Math.ceiling`.